# Сессии на стороннем хостинге на сохраняются

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, сессия, хостинг

На локальном хостинге дома  сохранятся сессии. У меня установлен wamp, где настройки автоматические. Теперь разместил сайт на стороннем хостинге  для всеобщего обозрения, там сессии на сохранятся. Видимо, нужно настроить что-то в базе.Кодировка стоит UTF-8. 
Написал в службу поддержки, не знают в чем причина. Если есть специалисту по данному вопросу откликнитесь. Как настроить хостинг, чтобы сессии сохранялись.
 Спасибо.

Comment: Сессии не зависят от базы они зависят от настроек сервера, есть вариант продлить им жизнь через htaccess/заголовок/php.ini, но вы по всей видимости не пробовали гуглить

Comment: В php.ini session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440, этого достаточно. Так же прописан код `  sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f w……….r@example.com
session.save_path = "/var/www/user/data/bin-tmp/"
upload_tmp_dir = "/var/www/user/data/bin-tmp/" ` , но в папке bin-tmp  не обнаружено не одной сессии. В начале скрипта прописано `require_once('inc.session.php');
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);
session_set_cookie_params(0);
session_start();` , и нет результата. К редактированию ini нет доступа.Кто-нибудь может подсказать причину не сохранения.

Comment: Что в подключаемом файле? start_session() должна быть практически выше всего, и выше заголовков

Comment: Что за хостинг?

Comment: В подключаемом файле корзина покупок. Сегодня ответили из службы поддержки и объяснили, что скрипты созданные на сервере Windows, работают не как на Linux. У меня на  Windows. php.ini не дают править.Продлить  жизнь через htaccess/заголовок/php.ini, можно узнать подробнее как и где это можно править?

Comment: Корзина покупок? Пробовали начать сессию до подключения корзины? В самом начале. Управление через htaccess это php_value. Что то типа `php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 86400`